# Material UI Grid Centring

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, centering

I am trying to understand Material UI's grid system and use it on React.js but so far it's a bit confusing. I want to center the spinner loader and the text at the center no matter the viewport size. I can get the first loader spinner to be placed in the middle but the text always seems to break alignment or sink to the bottom like it does in this bit of code. I think I have to use properties like xs={2} but not sure how they work really? Can I get some help with this?

here is my code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(6)
    },
    spinner: {
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
      minHeight: '100vh'
    }
  })
);

<Grid container spacing={0} direction="column" alignItems="center" justify="center" className={classes.spinner}>
      <Grid item>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="circle-notch" spin className={classes.spinner} size="5x" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Translate contentKey={labelKey}>Waiting for show to start</Translate>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
```

Comment: using Grid to center elements in the view port seems an overkill. Flex box might be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched flexbox as @sidecus . This grid was an overkill.

```
root: {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: ' 50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  },
  spinner: {
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is short but will work

```
<Grid item align="center">
```